# Can't find common super class - Proguard

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

Lately, I been working on push notification using firebase cloud messaging. I have used latest firebase dependencies and successfully integrated firebase push notification and it works like a charm. But when I enabled proguard to build release apk android studio gives following error :-

```
Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbcn] 
(with 1 known super classes) and [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbbt]
(with 1 known super classes)
```

My firebase dependencies are:-

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

And google services dependency is:-

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Please help me out. I have tried other ways, but it didn't worked out.

Comment: Downgrade your dependency and try to implement same versions dependency.

Comment: @Harshilkakadiya Will it be efficient if i downgrade the dependency? Ultimately, one day or another we have to update our dependencies for app.

Comment: Yes it will be efficient to downgrade, but make sure don't downgrade to much only 1 or 2 less than current.

Comment: @Harshilkakadiya  Could you please suggest me versions for the firebase dependencies?

Comment: refere this [https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android]

Comment: @Harshilkakadiya Will try and let you know ?

Comment: Suggestion: try to use for core-> 15.0.0 and for messaging-> 15.0.2 and in class path-> 3.1.4

Comment: @KabindraShrestha see the output of ProGuard in the release build log and do what it tells you to do; this should result in the configuration rules, which to write into the `.pro` file.

Comment: @MartinZeitler It says: Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting java type before 'com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbcn' in line 97 of file '\app\proguard-rules.pro'. What does it means?

Comment: @KabindraShrestha this means you have a syntax error in that file. add switch `-verbose` for detailed output and work on it, until all the complaints are gone. these two unknown classes might only be the tip of the iceberg. that one rule might rather be something alike `-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }`

Comment: @MartinZeitler it worked for me :) thank you !! includescriptorclasses.

Comment: @MartinZeitler have added '-includedescriptoclasses' but it gives following error message 'Unknown option '-includedescriptorclasses' in line 143 of file '\app\proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: @KabindraShrestha this is not what I've wrote. read again and compare. just refer to the user manual, alike everyone else might do that, including me. this would already have answered the question... and you will need way more rules than only this one. SO is not a free of charge coding service.